# FFMpeg Mobile video encoding stutter

Tags: android, mobile, ffmpeg, h.264, video-encoding

I have been playing around with ffmpeg and video encoding and even though my mp4's work great on desktop, they are smooth etc they are terrible on mobile devices. They stutter and load very slowly and I am trying to figure out the problem.

As an example I made a page using the media element plugin: http://mediaelementjs.com/ and on it I first placed the video that comes with mediaelementjs and it worked well, it scaled to desktop and mobile and loaded quickly and played without any stutter.

However I loaded my video and it was slow and full of stutter, but only on mobile. So I thought it might be S3 (where it is hosted) but saved the file locally and same thing.

I am hoping someone who knows h.264 and/or ffmpeg can point me in the direction of why; here is the current command I am running on ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i $input_file_name -vcodec libx264 -r 100 -bt 300k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 192k -strict -2 -y $output_temp_file 2>&1
```

So what have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what have I missed?

Mobile devices have a very limited computing power. You are trying to play 100fps video file - there aren't any mobile device i know that can handle such framerate.

First - change framerate to reasonable value, then adjust resolution, set encoding profile (baseline, for example), video bitrate (quality, rate-factor). After that you can try out your files.

Comment: Thanks tried some of your advice and got it working, I will try some more stuff to get it compatible with both big and small screens, I have lost quite a bit of quality to deal with smaller devices so Ima just tweak it a bit and then accept

Comment: Yep got this working pretty well on: `ffmpeg -i ./3.mp4 -vprofile baseline -vcodec libx264 -r 40 -bt 5K -s 960x540 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 192k -strict -2 -y ./4.mp4 2>&1` now, looks good enogh on desktop and loads and plays awesome on mobile, thanks

Comment: Hey I just have one more question. I noticed a difference between my local encoder and my cloud encoder on AWS. I noticed that if I had a bitrate of 5K on my aws instances it caused grey frames with artificats on. Taking out the bitrate fixed it however do I have problems by taking out the bitrate? Should I go to the effort of updating my cloud encoder to match my local encoder to get this working right?

Comment: I should note I have tried the cloud encoded file on both desktop and mobile, but it was only one random file from my phone, maybe the bitrate will kill me for other files?

Comment: Grey frame means that frame was discarded while decoding. New versions of FFMPEG has slightly different command-line switches, for example, in new ffmpeg to set profile for video encoder `-profile:v` used instead `-vprofile`. By default ffmpeg will use High profile, which can include features, that android decoder in your device couldn't handle. That can lead to grey frames, artifacts, stuttering and other funny things.

Comment: Ok Kool, though I don't think this is isolated to android cos I get the grey frames on desktop too if I add the bitrate

Comment: In that case i have another suggestion. If grey frames appear in same order each time you play video, this can be one of three cases - cloud encoder produce incorrect files, files get damaged when you downloading them or cloud encoder uses High10 profile and your PC decoder doesn't support it.