# Error Converting MOV to MP4 with avconv

Tags: mp4, avconv

I use:

```
avconv -i '/INPUT.MOV' -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec aac \
-strict experimental -r 24 -b 255k -ar 44100 -ab 59k 'OUTPUT.mp4'
```

The conversion is done correctly and smoothly plays PC / MAC, but the video does not play on mobile devices.

Does anyone have the same problem? How to solve it?

Comment: you may need to use -pix_fmt yuv420p [also ffmpeg git master?]

Comment: I added the new parameter and both ffmpeg as aconv continues without displaying on mobile :(

Comment: well I'm not certain... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801240/ffmpeg-mobile-video-encoding-stutter or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560852/convert-mp4-to-maximum-mobile-supported-mp4-using-ffmpeg may help

Comment: Mobile: Android and iOS have very particular screen size and audio settings.

Add: -s 720x480 -aspect 1.77 
Change:  -ab 59k to -ab 56k and -b 255k to -b 800k (or higher)
Put '-strict experimental' just before -acodec

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for your response, but does not play. I use now:
_avconv -i input.MOV -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec aac -strict experimental -s 720x480 -aspect 1.77  -r 24 -ar 44100 -b 800k -ab 56k output.mp4_
This is the command I use, you see something wrong??

Answer (score 0):

-strict experimental goes before -acodec.

In your script it is written after -acodec

Best regards,

Tomás Hernández